# ScrollView don't scroll util end

Tags: android, scrollview

I really do not understand why in a device with a small screen the scrollview not scroll to the end.
Look q'm saying:

[image: small screen]
[image: normall/big screen]

I researched and saw that could be caused due to the 'margin' but I do not remember to be using.
Here is my layout file with the ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="br.com.petrobressa.Inicio$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTextLabel"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/view">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:hint="Agendar para o dia..."
                android:imeActionLabel="Data"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_today"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Selecionar horario:"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />



                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivImageNotificar"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Este horario ja foi reservado!"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/tvNotificar" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Selecionar tipo de veiculo:"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />


        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />



        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reservar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorIcons"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="50dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try removing `layout_weight="1"` if that doesn't work then remove `fillViewport="false"` too

Comment: not worked for me :/

Comment: it works on my device..it does scroll to the end

Comment: Your device is QVGA (240 x 320 ldpi) ?

Comment: Oh, no not that much smal

Comment: I believe that my screen is this :/ but this should worker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104124/discussion-between-helio-soares-junior-and-qandeel-abbasi).